# JComboBox itemStateChanged event called twice at a time

Tags: java, swing

```
resultCombo = new JComboBox();
resultCombo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
         sampleText=resultCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
         System.out.println("SampleText : "+sampleText);
    }
});


output:
SampleText : selectedword
SampleText : selectedword
```

Why this event is called twice when selecting item in combobox.?

Comment: Thank u for your answers, i used this for selected item and it works fine.
         if(ie.getStateChange() == 1)

Comment: Use `e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED` instead. It is more easier to understand for someone else who is reading your code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JComoboBox ItemListener does get called twice for a single change. Once for SELECTED event and once for DESELECTED event.

See [this tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) on how to write an ItemListener.

Basically what you have to do is

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        //Do any operations you need to do when an item is selected.
    } else if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
        //Do any operations you need to do when an item is de-selected.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of [`ItemListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html#itemStateChanged%28java.awt.event.ItemEvent%29)

> Invoked when an item has been selected or deselected by the user. The
>   code written for this method performs the operations that need to
>   occur when an item is selected (or deselected).

This suggested that you will receive an event when an item is deselected or selected.  Seen as a change in the selected item in the combo box requires that the currently selected item has to be deselected first, it stands to reason that you will receive a `ItemEvent.DESELECTED` and `ItemEvent.SELECTED` event