# Duplicate output with ItemStateChanged listener on JComboBox

Tags: java, combobox, listener, netbeans-8

I have a JComboBox and after every change I want to print out the selected item. This is the code for my JCombobox:

```
mycombobox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
```

And my event looks like this:

```
private void mycomboboxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            

    System.out.println(mycombobox.getSelectedItem());

}
```

Everything works, but I get a duplicated output in my console like this:

[image]

The output should looks like:

```
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

NO DUPLICATE! Question is different to others because I want to print out the result and I'm using another event! What do I have to do, that only once the selected item appears in my console?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926397/jcombobox-itemstatechanged-event-called-twice-at-a-time

Comment: Thank you, you have to get the stateChange from your event and then you can write an if-statment for it like you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to get the stateChange from your event.

```
if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

     System.out.println(mycombobox.getSelectedItem());

}
```

The output is now unique.